# Gerrit pushing/replicating different gits to different servers - how?

Tags: git, repository, gerrit

Wondering if the subj is possible and how to achieve it.

We're working with android `repo` tool and the manifest points to different git servers for different `<project>`s.

is it possible to setup Gerrit to push reviewed changes to the corresponding server of each git ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done through Gerrit's replication feature.  See the documentation at http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.2.1/config-replication.html.  You can use different 'users' to push to the different servers, and Gerrit will use the permissions on those users to see which projects to push.